# ページ先のJSON表記をテーブルに変更する方法

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

---目的---
検索ボタンを押し、画面遷移先のJSON表記をテーブルにコンバートしたい。
---現状---
画面遷移した場合JSON表記のまま表示される。
---補足---
手探りで始めましたが、そもそも画面遷移先にはJSやjQueryの影響を与えることは出来ないのか、もしくはやり方が間違っているのかの質問です。
JSを一つのファイルにまとめてはいますが、それぞれ動作確認はとれています。
---環境---
WEBアプリ作成中でHTML、JS、Javascriptを使用しています。

```js
　　　//サジェスト機能、スニペットでは確認はとれないかと思いますが、問題なく作動。
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#ac2").autocomplete({
        source: function(req, resp){
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://127.0.0.1:8180/api/stockcars/keyword",
                type: "GET",
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    car_name : req.term
                },
                success: function(o){
                    resp(o);
                },
                error: function(xhr, ts, err){
                    resp(['']);
                }
          });

        }
    });
　　　　//JSON表記をテーブル変換。画面遷移先に関連付けできない。
    $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'http://localhost:8180/api/stockcars/search?q=',
          dataType: 'json',
          jsonpCallback: 'data',
          success: function(json){
            var rows = "";

                 $.each(json, function(i, item){


                    $.each(item,function(key,value){
                    rows += "<tr>";
                    rows += "<td>";
                    rows += key;
                    rows += "</td>";
                    rows += "<td>";
                    rows += value;
                    rows += "</td>";
                    });

                });
                //テーブルに作成したhtmlを追加する
                $("#tbl").append(rows);
          }
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="./js/jquery.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery-ui.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script src="js/Suggest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="get"action="http://localhost:8180/api/stockcars/search?q=" Accept-charset="UTF-8" onsubmit="doSomething();return false;">
<input type="text"  id="ac2"  name="car_name" >
<input type="submit" onclick="return test()" value="検索"></form>

</body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: 遷移先はどのようなHTMLなのでしょうか。そして、それは変更出来ますか？

Comment: サーバ側でJSONを返さずに加工済みのHTMLを返せば済むと思うのですが、それはできないということでしょうか。

Comment: miy様　int32_t様

コメントありがとうございます。
EclipseでAPIを動かしてローカルにデータを表示させているみたいです。なので単純にリンク先を表示しようとしても表示されずEclipseでWEBアプリを動かして表示するといった手法です。
HTMLをテーブルにして表示するといったことは出来ないです。
説明不足申し訳ございません。

Comment: JSONのURLに「遷移」する必要はありますか? つまり、ブラウザのアドレスバーがJSONのURLのものになる必要はりますか?  それとも、JSONをテーブルとして表示できればページ遷移なしでもOKですか?

Comment: int32_t様
今現在の手段であったのでページ遷移なしでも全く問題なくおっしゃる通りテーブル表示できれば問題ありません。

Comment: であれば、提示されているコードの最後のappend(rows)の前に「document.body.innerHTML="<table id=tbl></table>";」とか入れておけばいいのではないでしょうか。